# externally access processing via cmd

Tags: c#, processing

As I aksed in another post, I am trying to automate running processing ide from c#. Finally I found the way to run the processing sketch via cmd, with setting the installed processing folder in the path of evironment variable. 
I find it works with inputting command directly in cmd.exe, but when I want to do the same thing through some c# code in Visual Studio, it doesn't run the .pde file.
Here is the code,

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Runprocessing
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo stinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            stinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            stinfo.Arguments = "/c"+"processing-java --run --sketch=D:\\pw --output=D:\\pw\\output";
            stinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            stinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process = Process.Start(stinfo);

            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how should I properly use processing-java to activate the sketch. because here I am stating

```
stinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
stinfo.Arguments = "/c"+"processing-java --run --sketch=D:\\pw --output=D:\\pw\\output";
```

Is this the right way to use processing-java in cmd?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just in case you were wondering .. "not working" is not actually a question. So.. one more time, what is your question?

Comment: @JK. excuse me for my innocent. I am really new to programming, so sometime I might not explain myself clear enough.please note me if I am not explaining my question clear enough.

Comment: Programming questions aside, you need a space in your Arguments string after "/c".

Comment: @TomBlodget you're right. but even I changed that, still doesn't get processing run.I tried exactly the same method to open a txt file an jpg file, it's working well.anyway, thanks for you kind answer.

Comment: What happens when you run the same command yourself using the Windows command line?

Comment: @vesan it will run the .pde file as it should. I finally make it work. I make a windows form application project instead of a console application.